# Rectangles and Diagonals.

Tags: puzzle, rectangles

A 4×4 table has 18 lines, consisting of the 4 rows, the 4 columns, 5 diagonals
running from southwest to northeast, and 5 diagonals running from northwest to
southeast. A diagonal may have 2, 3 or 4 squares. Ten counters are to be placed, one in each of ten of the sixteen cells. Each line which contains an even number of counters scores a point. What is the largest possible score?

I drew a table with 4 rows and 4 columns and 10 diagonals as described above, and I placed the counters in the boxes. I got the score of 6.

[image: Diagram for above problem]

Comment: We saw this problem a few days ago with a higher claimed score, $13$ if I recall correctly.  Was it you?  I couldn't find it so maybe it has been deleted.

Comment: If you start with all the black squares and add two more you get a higher score.

Comment: I removed the [tag:game-theory] and [tag:diagonalization] tags. Please take a look at the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: Don't delete and re-ask questions. Since this version is better with the image, I'll let it stand, but note that re-asking questions can be grounds for a suspension. Edit the original instead in future.

Comment: This seems like an incredibly contrived setup. What's the inspiration for this question?